# Prime ideals of $\Bbb C[X, Y]$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, maximal-and-prime-ideals

This is an exercice of an Algebraic Geometry course.

In a way to study all the irreducible varieties in the affine two dimensional complex space, we are looking for the prime ideals of $A=\Bbb C[X,Y]$. The exercice proposes to study it in different cases. We will also use localization of rings. Here is one case I'm struggling with.

So let $P$ be a prime ideal of $A$ such that $P \cap\Bbb C[X] = 0$ and $S = \Bbb C [X]  \setminus 0 $.
We see that $AS^{-1} \cong \Bbb C(X)[Y]$ and that $PS^{-1}$ is a prime ideal of $AS^{-1}$.

My problem is the next step where we have to show that if $P \neq 0$, then there exists a irreducible polynomial $f \in \Bbb C(X)[Y]$ such that $PS^{-1} = (f)$.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Well, $\mathbf C(X)[Y]$ is a P.I.D. since $mathbf C(X)$ is a field.

Comment: I was sure it was not that complicated. Thanks a lot Bernard !